# Msgraph - download .eml as itemAttachment from msgraph api

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, attachment, email-attachments

I got method called `createObjectFromNotification` that creates email from notification
**resource.url** sample `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AQMkAGFkYmM2YzJiLTM3OTItNDE0ZS1iMmIw`

we get the message attachment in the same api call then filter file attachement , item attachment
I create file attachment from ***contentBytes*** but I made extra call to get item attachment

> GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value

Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message
but I got the file truncated  I will show example below
and pieces of my code

```
private async createObjectFromNotification(resource: EmailResource) {
      const email = await this.repository.getEmail(resource.url);
   .... etc
  }

public async getEmail(url: string): Promise<IncomingEmailInfo> {
    const result: MSGraph.Message = await this.getResource(url, {
      select: [
        "uniqueBody",
        "body",
        "sender",
        "toRecipients",
        "ccRecipients",
        "bccRecipients",
        "createdDateTime",
        "subject",
        "conversationId",
        "hasAttachments",
      ],
      expand: ["attachments"],
    });

    var attachments =
      result?.attachments
        .filter((attachment) => MSGraph.isFileAttachment(attachment))
        .map(
          (attachment): EmailAttachment => {
            return {
              name: attachment.name,
              cid: attachment.contentId,
              content: (attachment as MSGraph.FileAttachment).contentBytes,
              contentType: attachment.contentType,
              isInline: attachment.isInline,
            };
          }
        ) ?? [];

    await Promise.all(
      result?.attachments
        .filter(
          (attachment) =>
            attachment["@odata.type"] === "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment"
        )
        .map(async (attachment) => {
          const res = await this.getResource(
            `${url}/attachments/${attachment.id}/$value`,
            {}
          );
          console.log("result ", res);
          attachments.push({
            name: attachment.name,
            cid: attachment.id,
            content: res,
            contentType: attachment.contentType,
            isInline: attachment.isInline,
          });
        })
    );

    return {
      id: result.id,
      from: result.sender.emailAddress.address,
      to: result.toRecipients.map((to) => to.emailAddress.address),
      cc: result.ccRecipients.map((cc) => cc.emailAddress.address),
      bcc: result.bccRecipients.map((bcc) => bcc.emailAddress.address),
      subject: result.subject,
      body: result.body.content,
      uniqueBody: result.uniqueBody.content,
      bodyType: result.body.contentType,
      conversationId: result.conversationId,
      attachments,
    };
  }

public async getResource(
    resource: string,
    params: {
      select?: string[];
      expand?: string[];
      filter?: string[];
      top?: number;
    }
  ) {
    const selectString = (params.select ?? []).join(",");
    const expandString = (params.expand ?? []).join(",");
    const filterString = (params.filter ?? []).join(",");
    const top = params.top ?? 10;

    const result = await this.axios.get(resource, {
      params: {
        select: selectString,
        expand: expandString,
        filter: filterString,
        top: top,
      },
      headers: {
        ...(await this.getAuthHeaders()),
        Prefer: "outlook.body-content-type='html'",
      },
    });
    return result.data;
  }
```

Mime file .eml

```
Received: from MN2PR12MB4453.namprd12.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:260::9)
 by DM5PR12MB2486.namprd12.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS; Wed, 7 Oct 2020
 14:25:58 +0000
Received: from DM6PR12CA0032.namprd12.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:5:1c0::45)
 by MN2PR12MB4453.namprd12.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:260::9) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.3455.21; Wed, 7 Oct
 2020 14:25:56 +0000
Received: from DM6NAM11FT046.eop-nam11.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:5:1c0:cafe::b1) by DM6PR12CA0032.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10b6:5:1c0::45) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.3433.37 via Frontend
 Transport; Wed, 7 Oct 2020 14:25:56 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 166.78.70.105)
 smtp.mailfrom=circleci.com; berwickinsurance.com; dkim=pass (signature was
 verified) header.d=circleci.com;berwickinsurance.com; dmarc=bestguesspass
 action=none header.from=circleci.com;compauth=pass reason=109
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of circleci.com designates
 166.78.70.105 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=166.78.70.105; helo=m70-105.mailgun.net;
Received: from m70-105.mailgun.net (166.78.70.105) by
 DM6NAM11FT046.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.172.121) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.3455.23 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 7 Oct 2020 14:25:56 +0000
DKIM-Signature: a=rsa-sha256; v=1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=circleci.com; q=dns/txt;
 s=mailo; t=1602080756; h=List-Id: Content-Type: Mime-Version: Subject:
 Message-Id: To: From: Date: Sender;
 bh=qr9OzMq9dB7UxtaNoMl9iKG++HMSXYGSWMqbAR0B2Ko=; b=cGFIguoJnU3pxWWY99Ts6CYx5yfpd2BB+heNB7EdwurGUQ3T1sQ09ISHrnpmpEtzohF4X33X
 lwpOgykgclZWdalzxRx/i3Y3kim8eyiRnzXkUsNvkSgnE5NsKOyrENgZ0GZKfmHYla8VDFxr
 h3FXZ1SHhDARw1xY84s5Xz3TqbI=
X-Mailgun-Sending-Ip: 166.78.70.105
X-Mailgun-Sid: WyJkZjVlMCIsICJtaW5hLmZhd3p5QGJlcndpY2tpbnN1cmFuY2UuY29tIiwgIjg2OTgiXQ==
Received: from circle-legacy-notifier-v1-d744c6cc9-wxpzz
 (ec2-34-197-216-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com [34.197.216.176]) by
 smtp-out-n01.prod.us-west-2.postgun.com with SMTP id
 5f7dcff357b88ccb562522f3 (version=TLS1.2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256); Wed, 07 Oct 2020 14:25:55
 GMT
Sender: builds@circleci.com
Date: Wed, 7 Oct 2020 14:25:54 +0000 (UTC)
From: CircleCI Builds <builds@circleci.com>
To: Bill Smith <billysmithsolutions@gmail.com>, Mina
 <mina.fawzy@berwickinsurance.com>, James Taylor <james77taylor@gmail.com>,
 elilondon <eli.london@yahoo.com>, Keith Gonyon <kgonyon@gmail.com>
Message-Id: <pruJDCxRI6yvrHRe4rhTQ.1602080754888@postal.circle-legacy-notifier-v1-d744c6cc9-wxpzz>
Subject: [Workflow] Failed: berwickinsurance/BerwickAgencyDashboards on
 master / build-deploy-staging (89847f4)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_766_1718740841.1602080754887"
User-Agent: postal/2.0.3
List-Id: <berwickinsurance.BerwickAgencyDashboards.notifications.circleci.com>
X-Mailgun-Track-Clicks: htmlonly
X-Mailgun-Track-Opens: yes
Return-Path: bounce+3ffd89.8698-mina.fawzy=berwickinsurance.com@circleci.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 07 Oct 2020 14:25:56.4288
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 a3204c6e-0b22-4756-e379-08d86acce797
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: e65bc842-237f-4291-9d3f-746dd87042eb:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 DM6NAM11FT046.eop-nam11.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: a3204c6e-0b22-4756-e379-08d86acce797
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: MN2PR12MB4453:
X-MS-Oob-TLC-OOBClassifiers: OLM:114;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:1;
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:166.78.70.105;CTRY:US;LANG:en;SCL:1;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:m70-105.mailgun.net;PTR:m70-105.mailgun.net;CAT:NONE;SFS:(4636009)(286005)(2160300002)(966005)(7846003)(1096003)(9686003)(26005)(110136005)(166002)(83380400001)(956004)(356005)(19810500001)(336012)(33964004)(8676002)(7636003)(83080400001)(7596003)(7066003)(131040200001);DIR:INB;
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 07 Oct 2020 14:25:56.0321
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: a3204c6e-0b22-4756-e379-08d86acce797
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: e65bc842-237f-4291-9d3f-746dd87042eb
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:
 DM6NAM11FT046.eop-nam11.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: MN2PR12MB4453
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:02.3920579
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.3433.045
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 ucf:0;jmr:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(20160514016)(750128)(520011016)(944506458)(944626604);
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
 =?utf-8?B?cEsyYmkwWm1WS3NLK2ViWHVpVjdWYmlhRUU1WXE4Q0FXWlNlYUpXZlpITHp5?=
 =?utf-8?B?Z2NZSk1KSDFxOUxmaTR2NExRTEtzQnIvS1JQa29FNUxTeHRURkhWcGhURkZW?=
 =?utf-8?B?bTRnNjdMYTNJQ3doSTdUTkFUK0VtaFU2VWRBS0F2dHBhRHBFUHVVVjduckYx?=
 =?utf-8?B?UExXV09yRk13dE5mYzFVZENWcml2TnhIU0llYWIrNWFXOUZ5dytTN0xjbE9p?=
 =?utf-8?B?eGtsaW1uUTRsZ3RLYlJzVGNhMUE0Q2ZFVmNoM0dpMEp3YWFlcUE4WG11QVlr?=
 =?utf-8?B?eCtLNVI5amdQdzZMblhJajRhQnFjMTg3M3dSWUc5TS9mVDZOOXdwbkF5d0FB?=
 =?utf-8?B?TWVXd2VEaE52Z2FYNmNHcEhWWitNOERhLzNLU2MzMkNMeUFtdVk4dW5DbXNO?=
 =?utf-8?B?cjVtMGtpdksyN1lPSWt4Y0tyUWJTU3NDQnh5VHIzYUoxbGV0cU9lK0FOcFZI?=
 =?utf-8?B?YjBVSXBWY2lkR0xwWDQyMjZXK3lQeHF4K2s3cWtXVGVQNS9vbjA0YkVkYTBW?=
 =?utf-8?B?RWVKcGNmMThweWZQK1E1bit5NnFhZk4zNlMxbUl4b0hDYi8rUmRFMEJmZXo1?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZitXRjRXQjlLeEI5c0puVDI0eWJpVkg2bUtIOFlXTGhYMkdXMktmMFo1SEtl?=
 =?utf-8?B?MHFYdzZKMGxlU3pqSG10REsxMWJYcnZuaEExenAzUjFZTlJJcmZSdnNuUXI3?=
 =?utf-8?B?V2N5Z3kvMk1UMDRHMkdqRG1ER1cxaG94b1hQVGROdW5paHRmMW0xYkhGQlRT?=
 =?utf-8?B?QUtOZ0RsaUlwQVFMbWR6aktMbUNqNnBjL1B2UEJUUHIxOHBmL2d4Y3ZEVUVL?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZFdaR0FPUXJuRmlSNnhlTWFiMGs1TTI0RmtGcWl5S2RjWXpKRmpJUFlwTXlO?=
 =?utf-8?B?Q09CRWlWcG4yTkNpYmIrSHg2RlZWNnowU3hWTnRsMGJzMWlMODdXb0ZvNGtO?=
 =?utf-8?B?eThRZVlGQVBaS3JTVWIzZlJNYkhmeVNlUmNYbGZUU2FpQU9USk5wRFFvQ2dv?=
 =?utf-8?B?TzZGanZsOGdnRSt1Qm9WMGo5LzdHZ1JYSERWWWtBWTRCMVFQRHNib1VoaU5h?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZGRRcXVxbEVaNDUxcUx0bnJCbkxlUG5qbVRmaUZ4K1pYbmtTMmdHKzRNSDBE?=
 =?utf-8?B?TkVJUTZVN0MzWWU1dkVJR3cyWlhYYVltK1kwS21yc2E4L2R2SytuRE5GMTBi?=
 =?utf-8?B?T2dTYkFLbVpSVXZSclJ6dVpGSUZONFJyTUdjelFCd1UxZHpJN2UxWkdCTDZM?=
 =?utf-8?B?VFQ0Ym1JbStxUXU5TE4wekxCMlVoQ3ZoV3VQckYyY1VJS0Y0eUp2Umh4aXhT?=
 =?utf-8?B?YnowbDlsa0Faa3ZobHVxbThIK1luVmxOSmVxQW9WN1N4TFpSMHVHZ0hvSmd2?=
 =?utf-8?B?dFRXSDZoMlJRUUtoQzVvS1pwNGhXUHArQk4zOERJVmQ5RlVKaTkrZ1VvdXB6?=
 =?utf-8?B?RTJDTHdXeUtpUWw3STIzaHk3T3BQNFU3OTEvU2I0c1RnN2Y2MHdsalIyTmtz?=
 =?utf-8?B?MVpmMGxET1VwaUt3Q3o0YitKSmY3NWMrQzIwcU04U09acm5DQXR3REhOK2Y4?=
 =?utf-8?Q?1MhExypur/B6Jn/6pv3uQcBZs=3D?=
MIME-Version: 1.0

------=_Part_766_1718740841.1602080754887
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Author: Bill Smith <billy.smith@berwickinsurance.com>
Triggerer: Ghostdog6
Status: Failed
Project: https://circleci.com/gh/berwickinsurance/workflows/BerwickAgencyDashboards
Workflow: https://circleci.com/workflow-run/aba23660-f46e-4ec1-8b7a-e1c2dc9946aa
Branch:
https: //circleci.com/gh/berwickinsurance/workflows/BerwickAgencyDashboards/tree/master
Commits:
build-deploy-1: Failed
https: //circleci.com
https: //twitter.com/circleci


------=_Part_766_1718740841.1602080754887
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
=3D"box-sizing: border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0"><head style=3D"box-siz=
ing: border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0">
margin: 0">@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    body {
        padding: 0 !important
        }
    h1, h2, h3, h4 {
        font-weight: 800 !important;
        margin: 20px 0 5px !important
        }
    h1 {
        font-size: 22px !important
        }
    h2 {
        font-size: 18px !important
        }
    h3 {
        font-size: 16px !important
        }
    .container {
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important
        }
    .content {
        padding: 0 !important
        }
    .content-wrap {
        padding: 10px !important
        }
    .invoice {
        width: 100% !important
        }
    }</style></head>
othing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; color:#898989; font-fami=
ly: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; height:100%; l=
ine-height: 1.6em; background-color:#f6f6f6; width:100% !important" height=
cal-align: top" valign=3D"top"></td>
        <td class=3D"container" width=3D"600" style=3D"box-sizing:border-bo=
ont-size: 20px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; line-height:20px" valign=3D"to=
g: border-box; font-size:80px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; line-height:80p=
ont-size: 30px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; line-height:30px" valign=3D"to=
und-color: #fff; border:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius:3px; max-width:560p=
size: 14px; margin:0">
                <td class=3D"alert bad" style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; fon=
t-size: 16px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; border-radius:3px 3px 0 0; color=
font-size: 14px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; padding:20px; width:568px" va=
x-sizing: border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0; color:#337ab7; text-decorati=
on: none">Bill Smith</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
       =20
        <tr class=3D"project" style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14p=
e: 14px; margin:0">
          <td class=3D"name" style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px=
t-size: 14px; margin:0; color:#337ab7; text-decoration:none"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
       =20
      </tbody>
    </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table class=3D"secondary" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" =
style=3D"box-sizing: border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0; margin-top:20px; =
background-color: #fff; border:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius:3px; max-wid=
th: 560px; display:block" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff">
              <tr style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0"=
font-size: 14px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; padding:20px; width:568px" va=
izing: border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0; width:100%" width=3D"100%">
      <tbody style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0">
        <tr style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0">
          <td class=3D"name" style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px=
ng: border-box; font-size:14px; margin:0">
                <tr style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px; margin:=
ng: border-box; font-size:12px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; padding:0 0 20=
=3D"http: //email.circleci.com/c/eJxdUMFugzAM_Rq4gdIQQjhw6IaqbbdVu0-JEyAqSVA=
yle=3D"box-sizing: border-box; font-size:12px; margin:0; color:#999; text-de=
coration: underline">CircleCI</a>.
                    <br style=3D"box-sizing:border-box; font-size:14px; mar=
gin: 0">Unsubscribe by
                      <a href=3D"http://email.circleci.com/c/eJxdkMFugzAMhp=
n: 0; color:#999; text-decoration:underline">changing your email notificatio=
n: 0">
                    <td class=3D"aligncenter content-block" style=3D"box-si=
zing: border-box; font-size:12px; margin:0; vertical-align:top; padding:0 0 =
argin: 0">
                      <a href=3D"http://email.circleci.com/c/eJwtj8tugzAURL=
ox-sizing: border-box; font-size:12px; margin:0; color:#999; text-decoration=
ref=3D"http: //email.circleci.com/c/eJwljkFugzAQRU8DOyOTGHu88KJqFLXZJcoFhokp=
cal-align: top" valign=3D"top"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <img width=3D"1px" height=3D"1px" alt=3D"" src=3D"http://email.circleci=


------=_Part_766_1718740841.1602080754887--
```

***UPDATE***
I tested with postman the same result
[image]

Comment: Just to isolate the issue i would try the same Graph API call in POSTMAN or with Microsoft Graph Explorer to see if it works or not.

Comment: yea that what I did, the same result

Comment: Whats the attachment size looks like?

Comment: You can try this:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages('AAMkADA1M-zAAA=')/attachments('AAMkADA1M-CJKtzmnlcqVgqI=')/?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item

Comment: "contentType": "message/rfc822","size": 36714, but on postman the size is 6.48 KB

Comment: how I can save the file with $expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item call

Comment: Can you clarify when you say the file is getting truncated, you meant to say the entire mime(.eml) is not shown when you make the call or file is not getting downloaded?

Comment: I figure this out while uploading the file its truncating so I change the way I create eml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this out I was creating EML with the Mac Mailer app and while it's uploading the file its truncating the file but with Outlook it's working just fine

Comment: yea Thanks a lot